# can someone help me with my Formula Excel need it show blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

=IF(NOW()-B4>=15,"OK","Warning - Time to Renew")

that is the formula, but can it stay Blank until a date is put into cell B4

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `=if(isblank(b4),"",IF(NOW()-B4>=15,"OK","Warning - Time to Renew"))`

Comment: sorry to get back to you late, but that stopped the formula from working, anything i can do to fix that.

Comment: @James Do you get an error, or is the cell blank?

Comment: @James what's the issue? I'm not even sure how your formula is supposed to work, subtracting an integer from a date?

Comment: @Raystafarian There is a date in B4. He want to find out when there is less than 15 days between the dates, although I think it should be `B4-NOW()`.